# Find all Invariant Subspaces of a liner transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$1)$ Let $V$ be a $4$-dimensional Vector Space, with a basis $\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2,\mathcal{E}_3,\mathcal{E}_4$. $\mathcal{A}$ is a Linear transformation on $V$, with the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find all $2$- and $3$-dimensional Invariant Subspaces.

Similarly,

$2)$ Let $V$ be a $5$-dimensional Vector Space, with a basis $\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2,\mathcal{E}_3,\mathcal{E}_4,\mathcal{E}_5$. $\mathcal{A}$ is a Linear transformation on $V$, with the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find all $3$- and $4$-dimensional Invariant Subspaces.

I saw these problems in my algebra book, but I couldn't find any clue. I think the method of $2)$ is similar to the one of $1)$. How to solve these?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You have a linear transformation $T$ described by a matrix $\mathbf{A}$.
An invariant subspace $W$ is a subspace such that 
$$
T[\mathbf{v}] \in W, \quad \forall \mathbf{v} \in W.
$$
An eigenvector $\mathbf{u}_{1}$ of $\mathbf{A}$ has such a property:
$$
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{1} = \lambda \cdot \mathbf{u}_{1} \in \text{span}\lbrace \mathbf{u}_{1} \rbrace.
$$
In other words, the span of $\mathbf{u}_{1}$ is a 1-dimensional invariant subspace. How can you form $2$- and $3$-dimensional invariant subspaces? That should be easy. It would be slightly more difficult to show that these are *all* invariant subspaces.

Comment: For matrix $1$, our eigenvectors are $e_2$ and $e_4$. However, the subspace span($e_1, e_2$) is invariant. Is this situation covered in your answer, and I'm just missing something? I don't know how to answer the OP's question but am genuinely interested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question with a fairly sophisticated answer that I do not know off-hand. I found useful information [here](http://www.tufts.edu/~mkilme01/MATH150_02/Ch2_pg29-35.pdf), particularly on page $34$. Thankfully your matrices are already block matrices, as it appears that generalized eigenspaces hold some significance (for example, $\text{Span}(e_1, e_2)$ is invariant, the generalized eigenspace containing the eigenvector $e_2$).

Hopefully, with this 'bump', someone smarter than me will come along to give you some direction.